# To run 1.5 ton ac

Tags: ac, generator, dynamo

i want to run a 1.5 ton ac through dynamo and generater(that run a dynamo)
for that purpose how much KVA dynamo required and also a diesel generator(how many hp/KVA) will be required.
NOTE:- generator is use for running dynamo

Comment: Your question make no sense.

Comment: Dynamos are turned by an engine... generators the same, unless perhaps converting ac to dc... Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

For a 1.5 ton A/C unit, a reasonable steady-state figure (assuming 85% load factor) is about 2.5 kVA.

However, as Charles Cowie pointed out, this may or may not handle turn-on demands. The general rule of thumb for the motor switch on the A/C is that it should handle 3 times the running current. A 7.5 kVA generator is almost certainly overkill, since the inertial in the generator will handle some of the short-lived starting surge - although the generator output will drop noticeably when the A/C kicks in.

So, the answer is somewhere between 2.5 and 7.5 kVA. 2.5 kVA may work, and 7.5 kVA will certainly work. Until you actually try your specific A/C unit with your gennie, there is no way to be certain if a lower-power generator will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamo is another word for generator. The term is not much used by engineers. It is sometimes interpreted as meaning a DC generator. A diesel generator set consists of a diesel engine driving a generator, usually an alternating-current synchronous generator, sometimes called an alternator. I will assume you are describing an ordinary diesel generator.

To select a diesel generator set to power an air conditioner (A/C), it is necessary to determine the rated input of the A/C unit. In addition, it will be helpful to determine the inrush and accelerating current drawn by the A/C unit when starting. Also determine if the A/C has a mechanism for preventing restarting within a very short time after shutting off. The A/C motor can have a particularly difficult time doing that. Look in generator supplier literature for guidance.

Unless the A/C load is only a small percentage of the generator rating, you can expect the generator voltage to drop considerably when the A/C starts. Even if the generator and A/C can tolerate that, other loads connected to the generator may not tolerate it.

Unfortunately, there is no easy answer to this problem. To determine analytically what is required, is likely to require more information about the generator and load than you can obtain. The advice of an experienced generator supplier may be your best resource.